# For competitive swimmers, why does drag increase when pushing off of the wall near the surface rather than deep in the water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, kinematics, drag

I found [this experiment](https://www.swimmingscience.net/swimming-turns-and-starts-guide-to-glide-and-depth/) which showed that there is the least amount of drag between 1.25 and 1.50m below the surface of the water, while there is increased drag at just 0.25m below the surface. [image]

The drag equation is $F=\frac12pu^2c_dA$, which only references density (p), velocity (u), the drag coefficient ($c_d$), and the cross-sectional area (A). Since the density of water should barely change with a 1 metre change in depth and the cross-sectional area doesn't change, what causes the change in drag? Does it have something to do with turbulence and displacing water above the surface? Is there a way to mathematically quantify or model this drag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because when you are near the surface you are making waves, and you have to  provide the energy for those waves.  For the same reason a submarine deep below the surface  can travel faster  than a surface ship: both have to push the water out of the way, but the surface shop also leave waves behind. A deep submare does not create surface  waves as it moves.

Comment: As an (old) competitive swimmer, it is actually easy to feel the difference. As a swimming official, it is easy to see the difference as well.

Comment: Interesting (and short) paper on this here   file:///C:/Users/Andre/Downloads/4578-Article%20Text-12479-1-10-20100809.pdf

Comment: @foolishmuse Would you be able to provide an online link to that paper? You seem to have shared the local file which I can't access.

Comment: @user426315  Yes, it is a difficult link  try https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3588683/ or a search for THE EFFECT OF DEPTH ON THE DRAG FORCE DURING UNDERWATER GLIDING: A CFD APPROACH